# Jquery regex : substitute <br/>

Tags: jquery, regex

This is my code :

```
$(".tooltip").live('click', function() {
    var texte = $('#tiptip_content').text();
    $('#subheader').html(texte);
});
```

`var texte` contains some texte with `<br/>` tags and `<b></b>` tag.
I would like to add this text to #subheader but with `<br/>` changed to "double space" and `<b></b>` tag deleted.

How can I do that please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for a non regex solution.

Since `.text()` strips out any `<elements/>` you can use `.replaceWith()` to change your `<br/>` to `&nbsp;&nbsp;`

```
var d = $('#tiptip_content').clone();
var texte = d.find("br").replaceWith("&nbsp;&nbsp;").end().text();
$('#subheader').html(texte);
```

**[Example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/83Lj9/1/)**

Comment: It might be that the element contained a string with the tagnames mentioned encoded. Then the regexp should work. But you're right, the text() function should have stripped out the elements by default

Answer (score 2):

```
texte.replace(/<b><\/b>/gi, '');
texte.replace(/<br\/>/gi, '  ');
texte.replace(/searchRegex/gi, 'replace');
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

The 'gi' stands for "global" (ie. replace every one) and "case-insensitive".
Note the escaping of the / character.

Comment: It's Javascript. Sure the <br/> doesn't have a space in (ie. <br />)?

Comment: You can capture both with regex: .replace/<br\s?\/>/

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following to remove all HTML tags from the string:

```
texte.replace(/<\/?[^>]+>/gi, '');
```